# asp.net: setup and navigate, then pass an id to navigate to that page. localhost:12345/companyid=?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, response.redirect, redirect

I saw some webpages have like: `http://nameofsolution/a=5` 
I have a project at hand, that. when I click on a hyperlink field company number, it navigates to a webpage that shows the details of the company from a query select * from table where companyid=thatHyperlinkFieldCompanyNumber.

It's like, I have a hyperlink showing 5 as the company id. when i click on it, i want it to navigate to a page and pass the companyid 5 to that page, so that I can pass 5 to the query to show the information table on that new page.

How do I do that please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you just asking about query string values?  Something like this?:  `http://www.example.com/?key=value`  Then in `index.aspx` you can get `value` from the query string value.

Comment: @David :hi hi, that's exactly the format I want, but I don't know how to set up the whole thing. I don;t even know the term for this to search some tutorials....